# Force text over 2 lines with CSS

Tags: html, css

I'd like to have all surnames on the second line AND maintain the exact same width for `test` div. What is the best way of achieving this with CSS?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="test">
    <h1>Mike S</h1>
</div>

<div class="test">
    <h1>Mike Smith</h1>
</div>

<div class="test">
    <h1>Mike Smiths</h1>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.test {width:25%;float:left;background:red;margin-right:20px}
h1 {text-align:center}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zcg9k5xh/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Update your code with this:

```css
.test {width:25%;float:left;background:red;margin-right:20px}
h1 {text-align:center}
h1 span{display: block;}
```

```html
<div class="test">
    <h1>Mike <span>S</span></h1>
</div>

<div class="test">
    <h1>Mike <span>Smith</span></h1>
</div>

<div class="test">
    <h1>Mike <span>Smiths</span></h1>
</div>
```

You can also do this by using css, update above css

```
h1 span{display: list-item;list-style:none;}
```

jsfiddle with this
http://jsfiddle.net/zcg9k5xh/2/

Comment: 10 seconds & I will - Stack have a waiting time :) Thanks again!!

Comment: @michaelmcgurk - I'd recommend simply adding `<br>` after the first name - unless you are specifically styling the content within `span`. That way your HTML is more semantic, and you arent forced to make a natively inline element block level.

Comment: @ SW4 You can use second option too, but using <br> is very bad habbit in UI design.

Comment: "I'd rather not use unnecessary markup. Would prefer to let CSS handle the cosmetic bits :)" You said no unnecessary markup, but now accept other tag that needs css. So <br> is only a html tal, <span> need to be closed and css... turning a inline element to block. I don't understand why.

Comment: @SwapnilMotewar can you explain why <br> is very bad habbit? And <span> turned block element its better?

Answer (score 5):

Given that it seems you are willing to change your HTML, I would recommend you simply add [**`<br>`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br) after the first name, instead of wrapping the last name in any other tags. This would be deemed best practice.

> The HTML `<br>` Element (or HTML Line Break Element) produces a line
>   break in text

This will give more semantic HTML- without the need to adjust native element styling, or clutter your DOM with uneccessary nodes.

```css
.test {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  background: red;
  margin-right: 20px
}
h1 {
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <h1>Mike<br>S</h1>
</div>

<div class="test">
  <h1>Mike<br>Smith</h1>
</div>

<div class="test">
  <h1>Mike<br>Smiths</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the word-spacing attribute to the child tag:

```css
.test {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  background: red;
  margin-right: 20px
}
h1 {
  background-color: blue;
  word-spacing: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <h1>Mike S</h1>
</div>

<div class="test">
  <h1>Mike Smith</h1>
</div>

<div class="test">
  <h1>Mike Smiths</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Great solution for when changing the HTML isn't an option

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what you are asking, it seems like the jsfiddle is what you are asking here.
But you can always set width to 100% so it cover for the text, if you want all that text in the same div then put it all under one Div tag.

Comment: Apologies.
I basically need the 'S' in 'Mike S' to drop to a second line.

Comment: @michaelmcgurk can you use a <br> tag?

Comment: I'd rather not use unnecessary markup. Would prefer to let CSS handle the cosmetic bits :)

Answer (score -4):

Is this what you want?

```css
.test {width:25%;float:left;background:red;margin-right:20px}
h1 {text-align:center}
```

```html
<div class="test">
    <h1>Mike</h1>
    <h1>S</h1>
</div>

<div class="test">
    <h1>Mike</h1>
    <h1>Smith</h1>
</div>

<div class="test">
    <h1>Mike</h1>
    <h1>Smiths</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: this is wrong from a W3C and SEO point of view. Use span inside of the h1 not 2 different h1